# Convergent sequence of functions and compact set contains the spectrum of the limit

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-algebras

Let  $K\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be a compact subset. Let $(x_n)$ be a convergent sequence of normal elements in a unital $C^*$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$, with limit $x$, such that $\sigma(x_n)\subseteq K$ for all $n$.

**Problems**:

(i) Suppose that $\sigma(x)\subseteq K$. Show that for every $f\in C(K)$, one has $f(x_n)\to f(x)$ in $\mathcal{A}$.

(ii) Show that $\sigma(x)\subseteq K$.

Normally, I do not have any problems dealing with similar sequences. I do not know where to start in (i). Any hints would be helpful.

Comment: Hint for (i): First show the statement for polynomials, then use Stone-Weierstrass.

Comment: @MaoWao Thank you for the comment. The problem is I do not know where to start. If I pick, let's say $f(y):=y^2$, how do I show that $f(x_n)\to f(x)$ in $\mathcal{A}$? I am currectly using the book "An Introduction to Operator Alegbras" by Zhu. I just started to read Chapter 15.5 (which introduces Stone-Weierstrass thm) yesterday and I am not sure how to apply it for this problem.

Comment: Try to mimick the proof that the square function on $\mathbb{R}$ is continuous. At some point you use that $|xy|=|x||y|$. This is no longer true if you replace the absolute value by the norm of $\mathcal{A}$, but you still have an inequality (submultiplicativity of the norm), and that is all you need here.

Comment: Polonomials can be built up by considering the constant functions then repeat: multiply by a scalar, multiply by the indeterminate $X$, and add two already obtained functions..

Comment: @MaoWao Okay, that makes sense. It's clear that the statement holds for polynomials. I do not understand why we need Stone-Weierstrass.

Comment: You need Stone-Weierstrass to approximate arbitrary continuous functions on $K$ by polynomials.

Comment: @MaoWao I think I'll sleep on it, as I have been stuck for hours to figure out how to prove it. Could you please show it to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I think one has to prove (ii) first because $f(x)$ is not well-defined if $\sigma(x)\not\subset K$.

(ii) Let $\lambda\in \mathbb{C}\setminus K$ and $f(z)=\frac 1{z-\lambda}$. Then
$$
\|(x_n-\lambda)^{-1}-(x_m-\lambda)^{-1}\|=\|(x_n-\lambda)^{-1}(x_m-x_n)(x_m-\lambda)^{-1}\|\leq \|f\|_{C(K)}^2\|x_m-x_n\|.
$$
Thus $(x_n-\lambda)^{-1}$ is a Cauchy sequence. Let's call its limit $y$. We have
\begin{align*}
\|y(x-\lambda)-1\|&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\|(x_n-\lambda)^{-1}(x-\lambda)-(x_n-\lambda)^{-1}(x_n-\lambda)\|\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\|(x_n-\lambda)^{-1}(x-x_n)\|\leq \|f\|_{C(K)}\lim_{n\to\infty}\|x-x_n\|\\
&=0.
\end{align*}
Hence $y(x-\lambda)=1$. Similarly one shows $(x-\lambda)y=1$. Therefore $\lambda\in \rho(x)$.

(i) As established in the comments, if $p$ is a polynomial, then $p(x_n)\to p(x)$. This follows from the continuity of addition and multiplication in $\mathcal{A}$. Now let $f\in C(K)$ and $(p_k)$ a sequence of polynomials such that $p_k\to f$ uniformly on $K$. The existence of such a sequence is guaranteed by the Stone-Weierstrass theorem. Then
\begin{align*}
\|f(x)-f(x_n)\|&\leq \|f(x)-p_k(x)\|+\|p_k(x)-p_k(x_n)\|+\|p_k(x_n)-f(x_n)\|\\
&\leq 2\|p_k-f\|_{C(K)}+\|p_k(x)-p_k(x_n)\|.
\end{align*}
Letting first $n\to\infty$ and then $k\to \infty$ yields the desired result.